# InnoSetup MsiQueryProductState

Tags: windows-installer, installation, setup-project, inno-setup

I want to replace the VS setup by the Inno Setup. Do check if an old version is installed i found the 'MsiQueryProductState' method.
I found several examples looking like this:

```
function MsiQueryProductState(ProductCode: string): integer;
  external 'MsiQueryProductStateA@msi.dll stdcall';
function MsiConfigureProduct(ProductCode: string;
  iInstallLevel: integer; eInstallState: integer): integer;
  external 'MsiConfigureProductA@msi.dll stdcall';
const
  INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT = 5;
  INSTALLLEVEL_MAXIMUM = $ffff;
  INSTALLSTATE_ABSENT = 2;
```

Checking for the product always returned 2 and not the required 5 value (INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT)

I found the mistake, I'll post it as an answer ...

Thank Freddy

Comment: If you find the solution yourself, you should post it as an answer. You can then mark it as accepted a few hours later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the Unicode version of the InnoSetup mixed with the ANSI version of function prototype. It was enough to replace the `MsiQueryProductStateA` with `MsiQueryProductStateW`.

If you use this conditionally defined script, InnoSetup compilation preprocessor will *find* the right version for the functions (Unicode or ANSI) depending on when you're using ANSI or Unicode InnoSetup.

```
[Code]
#IFDEF UNICODE
  #DEFINE AW "W"
#ELSE
  #DEFINE AW "A"
#ENDIF

function MsiQueryProductState(ProductCode: string): integer;
  external 'MsiQueryProductState{#AW}@msi.dll stdcall';
function MsiConfigureProduct(ProductCode: string;
  iInstallLevel: integer; eInstallState: integer): integer;
  external 'MsiConfigureProduct{#AW}@msi.dll stdcall';
```

Comment: +1, I've extended your answer with a little trick (originally founded by [kobik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/937125/kobik) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9670505/960757)). Could you review my edit and optionally rollback if you don't like it ? Thanks!